MySql.Data ExecuteNonQuery throws NullReferenceException
I installed a MySql.Data NuGet Package to my project
and tried to create table using ExecuteNonQuery.
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.Connection = con;
        string cmd = @"CREATE TABLE [TABLENAME] (
                    TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                    TAGNAME NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
                    MESSAGE NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
                    LIMITTYPE NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                    CLASSNAME NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                    STATE NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (TIMESTAMP, TAGNAME),
                    KEY IDX_[TABLENAME] (TIMESTAMP, TAGNAME)
                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
        sqlCommand.CommandText = cmd.Replace("[TABLENAME]", tableName);
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

You can see the code above.
However, when I execute that command, it throws NullReferenceException from sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();.
And, when I go to my MySql workbench I can find the table is created but also have a row with all null values which is not permitted.
Like this:

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?
I executed the query from workbench itself and there is no row inserted.
I want to create a table only without insert a row.
Edit
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Dispose()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Here's the stack trace.

That's not a row with null values, that's just a placeholder row for you to edit in the GUI if you so wish.

There is no row being inserted. What you are seeing is the data entry row provided by that management app. That's where you enter new data to be inserted. Give it a try and you'll see. The asterisk in the row header is supposed to indicate unsaved data. The .NET WinForms DataGridView control works the same way, as does just about every database management app.

As for the NullReferenceException, there's nothing in the code you have provided that looks like it should cause that. Please provide the stack trace from the exception. ALWAYS provide the stack trace. It is provided as a diagnostic tool so, if you'd like us to diagnose the issue, providing that information should be an obvious step. It won't always be needed but it should always be provided in case it is.

@Shadow If so, why is that placeholder not there when I execute the query from workbench?

@jmcilhinney I added a stack trace

Doesn't shed much light on the issue form me, I'm afraid. Maybe someone more familiar with MySQL will have a better idea. One thing I would be interested to know is whether ExecuteNonQuery works for other statements, e.g. UPDATE or DELETE. I wonder whether there is some issue that will show up every time.

What is the value of tableName?

"why is that placeholder not there when I execute the query from workbench?". Probably because that's just showing the results of a query, rather than the entire contents of a table. A query could involve multiple tables, views, functions, etc. Only a limited subset will involve all columns from a single table so there's no good reason to display a data entry row for any query results.

@i486 The value is ALARM_LOG

Oracle's MySql.Data is very buggy, badly maintained and even fakes features, eg "asynchronous" calls just start another thread. Most people use the truly open source MySqlConnector provider which fixes many of the bugs in Oracle's provider. The open source provider is actually more popular than Oracle's. There's little reason trying to troubleshoot Oracle's provider. Even if this is a bug, it may not be fixed for years

What happens if you use MySqlConnector ? The code you posted doesn't have to change, only the package.

@jmcilhinney I tried the INSERT only, but it works pretty well. The exception only occurs when I create the table.

@jinsik556 what happens if you use MySqlConnector? I can't stress enough that there's no point troubleshooting Oracle's driver. Oracle doesn't even investigate bugs. On the other hand, a possibly similar issue was reported for MySqlConnector, caused by server-side errors or incorrect thread access. The maintainers tried to reproduce the problem and eventually fixed it. Oracle wouldn't even respond to a ticket.

@PanagiotisKanavos I tried to install MySqlConnector using NuGet. I'm using Framework 4.5 so I installed MySqlConnector 1.3.14. But after the build, when I try to connect, It throws an exception saying Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 6.0.0.0 which version is not used by MySqlConnector 1.3.14.

.NET Framework 4.5 is 12 years old and out of support for 8 years. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. Whatever bug you encountered was probably fixed in the past 10+ years but the fix will never be backported to an unsupported version.

OK... I found how to fix it.
The reason I think is NVARCHAR and
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 part.
I replaced NVARCHAR to VARCHAR and removed ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8.
Now it doesn't throw NullReferenceException. I think that it's because of the difference of MySQL version.
I previously used 5.7 and upgraded to 8.0.
Don't know exactly why but hope this answer helps someone like me.
Thanks to everyone who commented.
